# Adding ssh keyfile in jenkins gerrit trigger: "/...../.ssh/id_rsa" does not exist

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, key, gerrit

I installed git, gerrit and jenkins on linux, and I installed gerrit trgger plugin on jenkins.
Now I am setting the geerrit server, and trying to add the ssh key file, but it is giving me
error "/home/heidi/.ssh/id_rsa" does not exist, and Bad SSH keyfile or password.

just like the image on its offical website:
 https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger
（the one in "Administrative Settings"）

BUT, this location and file both are existing！
Why can't these keys be found?
I had trid the chmod command on .shh file and on those two keys.
but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a symptom of either

1. The key actually not existing (to which the answer from @nafas applies) or
2. The key is not readable by the `jenkins` user (which your self-answer alludes to)

If you are logged into your jenkins server, and you navigate to `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh` and do an `ls -lA` what you would likely see is that "root" or some other user owns the id_rsa private key you are attempting to use.

```
[RHEL7.2 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh]# ls -lA
-rw------- 1 root    root    1675 Jul 11 07:45 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     398 Jul 11 07:45 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  855 Jun 26 19:57 known_hosts
```

Logged in as root, or using sudo, you will want to change ownership of the user and group to reflect the jenkins user and group like so: `chown <user>:<group> file(s)`

```
[RHEL7.2 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh]# chown jenkins:jenkins id_rsa*
[RHEL7.2 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh]# ls -lA
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 1675 Jul 11 07:45 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  398 Jul 11 07:45 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  855 Jun 26 19:57 known_hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just create a key.

Log in to your local computer as the user running servers.
In a command prompt, run:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

> Just press  to accept the default location and file name. If
>   the .ssh directory doesn't exist, the system creates one for you.
>   Enter, and re-enter, a passphrase when prompted. The whole interaction
>   will look similar to this:

**SOURCE:**

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html

Comment: thank you, but I already generated a pair of SSH key, but jenkins still says "/home/heidi/.ssh/id_rsa" does not exist.....
why.....They actually exist!

Comment: yeah even i got the same problem. It exists but I keep getting the message that it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it...
post my solution here for someone who might encounter this problem int the future.
Note that the user of file jenkins which you installed.(in my case, /var/lib/jenkins and the user is "jenkins")
use "sudo su" then "su jenkins"
then generate a pair of ssh key in /var/lib/jenkins
it will no longer appear ".....dose not exist"
:)